# lower_case_table_names Settings in MySQL 8.0.12

Tags: mysql, lowercase, data-dictionary

I've just compiled the version MySQL 8.0.12 in a Ubuntu 16.0.4.

After following the instructions in the website and making the following my.cnf file:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data
socket=/tmp/mysql.sock
port=3306
log-error=/usr/local/mysql/data/localhost.localdomain.err
user=mysql
secure_file_priv=/usr/local/mysql/mysql-files
local_infile=OFF

log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log

# Remove case sensitive in table names
lower_case_table_names=1
```

I get the following error:

```
2018-08-11T19:45:06.461585Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-011087] [Server] Different lower_case_table_names settings for server ('1') and data dictionary ('0').
```

What should I change so that data dictionary is aligned to server settings?

Comment: I had the same problem and as described here https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=90695 this is not supported out of the box. So the workaround that I did in order to make it work was this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53103588/lower-case-table-names-1-on-ubuntu-18-04-doesnt-let-mysql-to-start?noredirect=1#comment93200315_53103588

Comment: At the time the database was first created a different value for `lower_case_table_names` was used, so you need to recreate the database.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per this [link](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=90814), lower_case_table_names should be set together with --initialize option.

Comment: Thank you very much. I should've imagined that, but I couldn't find any reference at any place.

Comment: Can you give me an example on how to use this option?

Comment: @ChristophAdamakis , the example that you require was already posted by Christian Fernando.

Comment: @PraveenE Where do you set the `--initialize` option?

Comment: @Thomas This is a command argument while starting the mysql. Refer https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-directory-initialization.html

Comment: does not work with deb / ubuntu releases as they initiate the db already!

Answer (score 68):

So far, I can get it to work with a workaround (I originally posted on [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/1261605/1060743)): by re-initializing MySQL with the new value for `lower_case_table_names` after its installation. The following steps apply to a new installation. If you have already data in a database, export it first to import it back later:

1. Install MySQL:

   ```bash
   sudo apt-get update    
   sudo apt-get install mysql-server -y
   ```
2. Stop the MySQL service:

   ```bash
   sudo service mysql stop
   ```
3. Delete the MySQL data directory:

   ```bash
   sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
   ```
4. Recreate the MySQL data directory (yes, it is not sufficient to just delete its content):

   ```bash
   sudo mkdir /var/lib/mysql    
   sudo chown mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql
   sudo chmod 700 /var/lib/mysql
   ```
5. Add `lower_case_table_names = 1` to the `[mysqld]` section in `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`.
6. Re-initialize MySQL with `--lower_case_table_names=1`:

   ```bash
   sudo mysqld --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/my.cnf --initialize --lower_case_table_names=1 --user=mysql --console
   ```
7. Start the MySQL service:

   ```bash
   sudo service mysql start
   ```
8. Retrieve the new generated password for MySQL user `root`:

   ```bash
   sudo grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysql/error.log
   ```
9. Change the password of MySQL user `root` either by:

   ```bash
   sudo mysql -u root -p
   ```

   and executing:

   ```sql
   ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPa$$w0rd';
   ```

   afterwards, OR by calling the "hardening" script anyway:

   ```bash
   sudo mysql_secure_installation
   ```

After that, you can verify the `lower_case_table_names` setting by entering the MySQL shell:

```bash
sudo mysql -u root -p
```

and executing:

```sql
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'lower_case_%';
```

Expected output:

```
+------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name          | Value |
+------------------------+-------+
| lower_case_file_system | OFF   |
| lower_case_table_names | 1     |
+------------------------+-------+
```

Comment: You save my life.

Comment: At this point I don't know how many times I came back to this brilliant answer to solve problems, you're the best

Comment: Yes this a great answer... but why is mysql like this?

Comment: I tried a lot but your answer worked for me mysql 8 and ubunutu 22. thank you very much.

Comment: If the service fails to start and you see a 'File '/var/lib/mysql/auto.cnf' not found (OS errno 13 - Permission denied)' error in your logs then this can be fixed by disabling selinux.

Answer (score 4):

MySQL Documentation says

lower_case_table_names can only be configured while initializing the server. **Changing the lower_case_table_names setting after the server is initialized is prohibited.**

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html

Answer (score 2):

The best way to **prevent** this problem is :**At first** add

```
[mysqld]
lower_case_table_names=1
```

then start mysql service for first time.

But anyway if you have started the server already,to solve your problem:

1.stop mysql:

```
systemctl stop  mysql
```

2.clean data directory or change the default, the following is for new installations , if you have data in your database **BACK UP** them beforehand

```
rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
```

3.Insert lower_case_table_names = 1 in your my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
lower_case_table_names=1
```

4.Start again

```
systemctl start mysqld
```

Comment: Thanks a lot its work, but I add only, [mysqld]  lower_case_table_names=1, Because systemctl command not working.

Comment: Incomplete instructions.   If you remove /var/lib/mysql and the binaries are gone.  Your step 4 wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue,

1. Just take the backup of the existing db Schema using the following command inside bin folder (/usr/local/mysql/bin)
   **./mysqldump -uroot -p password  > dump.sql**
2. Once the backup is taken delete the existing data folder in Mysql Home(/usr/local/mysql/) using the command
   **rm -rf data**
3. Now add the configuration as "**lower_case_table_names=1**" in my.cnf under **MYSQLD section** (/etc/my.cnf)
4. Now Initialize the data directory using the following command inside bin directory (/usr/local/mysql/bin)

**For Secure mode**
./mysqld --defaults-file=/etc/my.cnf --initialize --user=mysql --console

**For Insecure mode**
./mysqld --defaults-file=/etc/my.cnf --initialize-insecure --user=mysql --console

5. Once the data directory initialized, **For Insecure mode** repeat the Installation again and **For Secure mode** use the root password which is initialized during the run time of data directory Initialization.
6. Now import the existing dump file inside the Mysql Server using the command inside (/usr/local/mysql/bin) directory

**./mysql -uroot -p password  < file.sql**

Answer (score 0):

Edit the /etc/mysql/my.cnf file. Add this:

```
[mysqld]
lower_case_table_names=1
```

After that you have to reinstall mysql. Ubuntu would keep your current configuration files:

```
sudo apt purge mysql-server
sudo apt autoremove

sudo apt install mysql-server
```

Answer (score -1):

If anyone runs into this issue now, if you already initialized mysql, meaning you already had it up and running and then this error occurred, just comment out this line in the my.ini file.

```
lower_case_table_names=
```