# lower_case_table_names=1 on Ubuntu 18.04 doesn't let mysql to start

Tags: mysql, lowercase, ubuntu-18.04

I have installed mysql community server 8.013 on ubuntu 18.04 and I have the following issue.
I want to set lower_case_table_names=1 in order to have case insensitive table names in my db.
I edited /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf and added the following line under [mysqld]

```
lower_case_table_names=1
```

mysqld.cnf now is as follows

```
[mysqld]
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
log-error       = /var/log/mysql/error.log
lower_case_table_names=1
```

I stopped the mysql server using

```
sudo service mysql stop
```

Then I tried to start it again using

```
sudo service mysql start
```

but I get the following error

```
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

I tried

```
systemctl status mysql.service
```

and I got the following info

```
christoph@christoph-Latitude-E6530:/etc/init.d$ systemctl status mysql.service
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2018-11-01 16:38:14 EET; 24s ago
     Docs: man:mysqld(8)
           http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/using-systemd.html
  Process: 6681 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 6642 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql-8.0/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 6681 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Status: "SERVER_BOOTING"
    Error: 2 (No such file or directory)

Νοε 01 16:38:12 christoph-Latitude-E6530 systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
Νοε 01 16:38:14 christoph-Latitude-E6530 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Νοε 01 16:38:14 christoph-Latitude-E6530 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Νοε 01 16:38:14 christoph-Latitude-E6530 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

using journalctl -xe I got the following info

```
-- The result is RESULT.
Νοε 01 17:32:00 christoph-Latitude-E6530 sudo[2526]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Νοε 01 17:32:04 christoph-Latitude-E6530 wpa_supplicant[743]: wlp3s0: WPA: Group rekeying completed with 4c:5e:0c:7a:95:cf [GTK=CCMP]
Νοε 01 17:32:08 christoph-Latitude-E6530 gnome-shell[1565]: Some code accessed the property 'discreteGpuAvailable' on the module 'appDisplay'. That property w
Νοε 01 17:32:08 christoph-Latitude-E6530 gnome-shell[1565]: Some code accessed the property 'WindowPreviewMenuItem' on the module 'windowPreview'. That proper
lines 1349-1371/1371 (END)
Νοε 01 17:31:58 christoph-Latitude-E6530 systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has begun starting up.
Νοε 01 17:31:58 christoph-Latitude-E6530 audit[2593]: AVC apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=2593 comm=
Νοε 01 17:31:58 christoph-Latitude-E6530 kernel: kauditd_printk_skb: 28 callbacks suppressed
Νοε 01 17:31:58 christoph-Latitude-E6530 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1541086318.959:39): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name
Νοε 01 17:32:00 christoph-Latitude-E6530 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Νοε 01 17:32:00 christoph-Latitude-E6530 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Νοε 01 17:32:00 christoph-Latitude-E6530 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has failed.
```

I also tried to start the server using

```
sudo service mysql start --initialize lower_case_table_names=1
```

as described here
[lower_case_table_names Settings in MySQL 8.0.12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51803216/lower-case-table-names-settings-in-mysql-8-0-12/51804009?noredirect=1#comment93087502_51804009)
but I still get the same error and mysql doesn't start at all

If I run the following

```
sudo vi /var/log/mysql/error.log
```

I get the following cause of the error

```
Different lower_case_table_names settings for server ('1') and data dictionary ('0').
Data Dictionary initialization failed.
```

Any ideas why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Can you put spaces on either side of `=` in the config file, where you declare `lower_case_table_names`

Comment: No it didn't work. If I use lower_case_table_names = 2 it starts, but with lower_case_table_names = 1 , it never starts

Comment: Maybe reading this doc link may help: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html

Basically, having this variable as `1` is not recommended for case-sensitive OS

Comment: No setting it to 1 is recommended on all OS

Comment: It might be a bug on Mysql version 8.0 https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=90695

Comment: hmm. MySQL guys have closed it as a feature .. facepalm

Comment: According to this https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=90695 , the guys in Mysql suggest to start the server like this sudo service mysql start --initialize lower_case_table_names=1 but again it fails!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [lower\_case\_table\_names Settings in MySQL 8.0.12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51803216/lower-case-table-names-settings-in-mysql-8-0-12)

Answer (score 15):

In order to make this work in MySQL 8.0 and linux follow the steps bellow

0. Backup mysql schema before executing the following steps using

   mysqldump  -h localhost -u root -p mysql > /home/username/dumps/mysqldump.sql

and then stop mysql using

```
sudo service mysql stop
```

1. move or remove /var/lib/mysql directory. This will delete all databases!!!!

   ```
   mv /var/lib/mysql /tmp/mysql
   ```
2. Create a new /var/lib/mysql directory and make mysql user as owner

   ```
   mkdir /var/lib/mysql
   chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql
   chmod 750 /var/lib/mysql
   ```
3. edit /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf and add the following line after

   ```
   [mysqld]

   lower_case_table_names=1
   ```
4. Initialize mysql using the following

   ```
   mysqld --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/my.cnf --initialize lower_case_table_names=1 --user=mysql --console
   ```

Change defaults-file with the actual location of your defaults file.
more info on mysql initialization here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-directory-initialization-mysqld.html

5. (Optional) Repeat

   ```
   chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql
   chmod 750 /var/lib/mysql
   ```

if owner of the files in /var/lib/mysql is not mysql

6. Start mysql using

   ```
   sudo service mysql start
   ```
7. If everything worked correctly, open mysql using

   ```
   mysql -u root -p
   ```

and by running this query

```
SHOW VARIABLES where Variable_name like 'lower%';
```

you will get

```
'lower_case_table_names', '1'
```

8. Restore mysql schema using the dump created in step 0.
9. Execute mysql_upgrade to create the sys schema

Comment: I get this error when i try to initialize `mysqld`:

    "Too many arguments (first extra is 'lower_case_table_names=1')"

(Server version: 8.0.17-0ubuntu2)

Comment: Figured it out. Had to initialize this way: `mysqld --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/my.cnf --initialize --user=mysql --lower_case_table_names=1 --console`. Now it works!

Answer (score 14):

This worked for me on a fresh Ubuntu Server 20.04 installation with MySQL 8.0.20 (no existing databases to care about - so if you have important data then you should backup/export it elsewhere before doing this):

So... I did everything with elevated permissions:

```
sudo su
```

Install MySQL (if not already installed):

```
apt-get install mysql-server
```

Backup configuration file, uninstall it, delete all databases and MySQL related data:

```
cp /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf.backup
service mysql stop
apt-get --purge autoremove mysql-server
rm -R /var/lib/mysql
```

Restore saved configuration file, edit the file (add a line just under [mysqld] line):

```
cp /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf.backup /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
vim /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf

...
lower_case_table_names=1
...
```

Reinstall MySQL (keeping the configuration file), configure additional settings:

```
apt-get install mysql-server
service mysql start
mysql_secure_installation
mysql

SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'lower_case_%';
exit
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked to me after spending a day on this issue.

Answer (score 2):

You need to reinit MySQL data directory.
According to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html `lower_case_table_names` can only be configured when initializing the server.

You can do it using this script https://github.com/igrmk/ubuntu-reinit-mysql.

Please note that your data will be DESTROYED!
So create a backup before running it.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue.

I edited the /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf file. (NOT the /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf file.)

I inset the lower_case_table_names=1 just below [mysqld] line. (There were no lines below [mysqld] line below.

Then I restarted mysql using sudo service mysql restart

It solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please go to below location and add the following code

location - cd /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/

then `sudo vim mysqld.cnf`

next, add below under the [mysqld]

```
lower_case_table_names=1
```

Answer (score 0):

**On Mysql Server 8.0 Windows os**, if you change lower_case_table_names=2 in mysql.ini the server will not start so you have to follow this step 1: **Backup all data / export to .sql** or Dump all data step 2: Stop the server from service step 3: Delete the data folder from **C:\Program Files\ Mysql Server 8.0\Data** step 4: Open **C:\Program Files\ Mysql Server 8.0\my.ini** as an administrator using notepad step: 5 find set lower_case_table_names= 2 if you want camelCase table name step: 6 open mysql installer and **open reconfigure then open ->show advanced and logging option -> Advanced Option**s -> use second option from the list step: 7 then everything will be ok