# MySQL lower_case_file_system change (OFF to ON)

Tags: mysql, case-sensitive

I am trying to change the lower_case_file_system to 'ON' in MySQL, but do not know how to do it. I'd like to set it up as **case-non-sensitive**.

According to the MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual, '*This variable describes the case sensitivity of file names on the file system where the data directory is located. OFF means file names are case-sensitive, ON means they are not case-sensitive. This variable is read-only because it reflects a file system attribute and setting it would have no effect on the file system*.'

How can I change the value? Any idea, please? Thanks!

Carolina

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrKaa.png)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it's through XAMPP.

Do these steps:

1. open your MySQL configuration file: [drive]\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini
2. look up for: `# The MySQL server [mysqld]`
3. add this right below it: `lower_case_table_names = 2`
4. save the file and restart MySQL service

From: http://webdev.issimplified.com/2010/03/02/mysql-on-windows-force-table-names-to-lowercase/

In order to use `camelCaseNames` in table names and views, `lower_case_table_names` has to be `0`

Might want to check here too:

As per this [link](http://webdev.issimplified.com/2010/03/02/mysql-on-windows-force-table-names-to-lowercase/), lower_case_table_names should be set together with --initialize option.

If on Ubuntu:

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=90695 this is not supported out of the box. So the workaround is this
[lower_case_table_names=1 on Ubuntu 18.04 doesn't let mysql to start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53103588/lower-case-table-names-1-on-ubuntu-18-04-doesnt-let-mysql-to-start?noredirect=1#comment93200315_53103588)

Finally, read the official sources:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html
https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,377683

Answer (score 0):

**On Mysql Server 8.0 Windows os**, if you change lower_case_table_names=2 in mysql.ini the server will not start so you have to follow this
step 1: Backup all data / export to .sql or Dump all data
step 2: Stop the server from service
step 3: Delete the data folder from **C:\Program Files\ Mysql Server 8.0\Data**
step 4: Open **C:\Program Files\ Mysql Server 8.0\my.ini as an administrator** using notepad
step: 5 find set lower_case_table_names= 2 if you want camelCase table name
step: 6 open mysql installer and open reconfigure then open ->**show advanced and logging option -> Advanced Options** -> use second option from the list
step: 7 then everything will be ok

Comment: Please add proper formatting to your answer, its painful to read.