# Error creating AWS MySQL DB instance with lower_case_table_names set to 1

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm trying to create a new MySQL v8 db instance but I want lower_case_table_names turned on. I have created a new v8 parameter group and set this parameter to 1. I then go to create a new db instance and select this new parameter during the creation process.

The creation of the database gets stuck and if I check the log file in AWS Console I can see the following error over and over again:

> "Different lower_case_table_names settings for server ('1') and data
>   dictionary ('0')."

I saw this issue on SO - [lower_case_table_names Settings in MySQL 8.0.12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51803216/lower-case-table-names-settings-in-mysql-8-0-12/51804009#51804009) - which says that lower_case_table_names has to be used in conjunction with --initialize but surely it is as I'm creating a whole new db instance? Also, I'm not sure how to use --initialize in AWS Console!