# Unable to start MySQL 8.0.12 after lower_case_table_names Settings

Tags: mysql, database

I have same issue as the link per
[lower_case_table_names Settings in MySQL 8.0.12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51803216/lower-case-table-names-settings-in-mysql-8-0-12)

I followed the steps of stackprotector till step no 6 and log file show below

```
2021-06-18T09:35:13.134465Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2021-06-18T09:35:14.078706Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2021-06-18T09:35:14.966455Z 6 [Note] [MY-010454] [Server] A temporary password is generated for root@localhost: 5ip,8m>awvsJ
```

On step 7, i am unable to start the mysql server

The command i used is **mysqld** instead of mysql

```
sudo service mysqld start
```

I have the error log as below

```
2021-06-18T09:36:04.023595Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/libexec/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.21) starting as process 31701
2021-06-18T09:36:04.030626Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2021-06-18T09:36:04.030713Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012592] [InnoDB] Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
2021-06-18T09:36:04.030749Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012595] [InnoDB] The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to the directory.
2021-06-18T09:36:04.030777Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012270] [InnoDB] os_file_get_status() failed on './ibdata1'. Can't determine file permissions
2021-06-18T09:36:04.030809Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2021-06-18T09:36:04.030927Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2021-06-18T09:36:04.030989Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2021-06-18T09:36:04.031285Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.21)  Source distribution.
```

What's being wrong here?

I have grant all permission on

```
chmod 777 /var/lib/mysql
```